# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' - Assembler

Tags: assembly, cmake, x86, mingw, gnu-assembler

I wrote a sort function in C and then compiled it into assembler code (with help of the `-S` flag in GCC). When I try to compile this assembly code, GCC gives an error undefined reference to `WinMain@16'. Maybe it has something to do with my OS? I'll be glad to hear any advice, because I don't understand assembler at all.

Assembly code:

```
    .file   "quickSort.c"
    .text
    .globl  _partition
    .def    _partition; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_partition:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
    jmp L2
L4:
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    jl  L3
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    -8(%ebp), %edx
    leal    0(,%edx,4), %ecx
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    addl    %ecx, %edx
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%edx)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%edx)
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
L3:
    addl    $1, -8(%ebp)
L2:
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    16(%ebp), %eax
    jl  L4
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    16(%ebp), %edx
    leal    0(,%edx,4), %ecx
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    addl    %ecx, %edx
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%edx)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%edx)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .globl  _quick_sort
    .def    _quick_sort;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_quick_sort:
LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $40, %esp
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    16(%ebp), %eax
    jge L9
    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _partition
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    subl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _quick_sort
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    leal    1(%eax), %edx
    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _quick_sort
    jmp L6
L9:
    nop
L6:
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE1:
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0"
```

C program takes input from standard input as well as sort boundaries, then sorts the values ​​using an assembler function. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG4TR.png) - this is what I end up with, but if I build the project manually, gcc doesn't throw any errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define LN 100
#define ERROR(...) (printf(__VA_ARGS__))

extern void quick_sort(int *array, int x, int y);

// here is the rest of the code 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int left_border = INT_MIN, right_border = INT_MAX;     
    int return_code = read_border(argv, argc, &left_border, &right_border);

    if (return_code != 0) {
        printf("%d\n", return_code);
        return return_code;            
    } 
    int array[LN] = {0}, stdout_array[LN] = {0}, stderr_array[LN] = {0};  
    int count_elements = read_array(array, stdout_array, stderr_array, left_border, right_border);
    int sorted_array[LN] = {0};
    _memccpy(sorted_array, array, array[count_elements-1] - '0', count_elements * sizeof(int));
    quick_sort(sorted_array, 0, count_elements-1);
    int answer = count_sorted_elements(array, sorted_array, count_elements);

    print_stdout_or_stderr(stdout_array, stderr_array, array[0]);
    printf("%d", answer);
    return answer;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE C_SOURCES ./*.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ASM_SOURCES ./*.s)

add_executable(main ${C_SOURCES} ${ASM_SOURCES})

if(MSVC)
  target_compile_options(main PRIVATE /W4 /WX)
else()
  target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
endif()
```

gcc version: [image]

Comment: You tagged this [x86-64] and the code and your compiler/linker is 32-bit.I have changed the tag to [x86]. If you did mean to write 64-bit code then the code you have won't work in that environment.

Comment: The entry point for a windows program is __WinMain@16_ for 32-bit code. Can you show us the commands you use to assemble and link this code to an executable? From the looks of it `_quick_sort` is probably meant to be called from a _C_ program and this assembly code isn't meant to run standalone. If you are supposed to call this from C code, can you show us the C code?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: You're right, I actually call this function from a C program and gcc throws the error "error LNK2019: reference to an unresolved external quick_sort symbol in the main function." I thought that the problem is in the assembler code itself.

Comment: Appears you are using CMake. Can you also add your CMakeLists.txt file to the question? My understanding is you can build it manually and it works, but if you use CMake it doesn't? If that is not the case can you clear up what you mean?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yes it is. all programs on cmake were written by the teacher, I was required to implement sorting.

Comment: Most likely this is a name-mangling issue. It appears you are trying to pass the output of a compiler as your work. But that compiler is using a different name mangling, either because CMake builds in 64-bit and the stolen code was 32-bit (in Windows this makes a difference) or because CMake uses a much newer version of GCC than the one that produced the assembly code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: ok, can you tell me how can I get the compilation of 64 bit code?

Comment: Use MinGW64, or `gcc -Og -m64` if your current GCC supports it.